# Suppose that poynomial $x^4+x+1$ has multiple roots over a field of characteristic $p$ . What are the possible values of $p$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, field-theory, finite-fields

> Suppose that polynomial $x^4+x+1$ has multiple roots over a field of
>   characteristic $p$  . What are the possible values of $p$?

My solution : 
Set $f=x^4+x+1$. Suppose the multiple root is $m$ . So $f,f'$ (the formal derivative of $f$) have root $m$ in the field of characteristic $p$.

Hence $m^4+m+1=0 \pmod{p} $ and $4m^3+1=0 \pmod{p}$

So $3m+4=4(m^4+m+1)-m(4m^3+1)=0 \pmod{p}$ .

From here it is easy to to see that $p\neq 3$. I have no idea if it is possible to proceed any further. Please provide a solution.

Comment: But if $3m + 4$ and $4m^3 + 1$ have a common root, so does any linear combination of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:

Find the quotient and remainder when $(27)(4m^3 + 1)$ is divided by $3m+4$.

Comment: I obtained $27(4m^3+1)-(36m^2-48m+63)(3m+4)-229 $ . So the only possible $p$ is 229 .

Comment: Yes, $p=229$ is correct. But you need to prove that, mod $229,\,$ $f$ and $f′$ actually _have_ a common zero. Use the relations you already have. Start with $3m+4$.

Answer (score 4):

Using the [extended Euclidean algorithm](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=PolynomialExtendedGCD%5Bx%5E4+%2B+x+%2B+1,+4+x%5E3+%2B+1%5D) we get
$$
229 = (x^4 + x + 1)(144 x^2 - 192 x + 256)+(4 x^3 + 1)(-36 x^3 + 48 x^2 - 64 x - 27)
$$
This can also be found by computing the [resultant](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=resutant%5Bx%5E4+%2B+x+%2B+1,+4+x%5E3+%2B+1%5D) of $x^4 + x + 1$ and $4 x^3 + 1$, that is, the discriminant of $x^4 + x + 1$.

Answer (score 4):

$$3m+4 \equiv 0 \pmod{p} \\
3m \equiv -4 \pmod{p} \\
27m^3 \equiv -64 \pmod{p}$$

You also have 
$$4m^3\equiv -1 \pmod{p}$$

Denote $m^3=:x$ then
$$27x \equiv -64 \pmod{p} \\
4x \equiv -1 \pmod{p}$$

Multiply first equation by 4, second by 27 and subtract.